# WIndows phone 8 - Typing in TextBox dynamically gives results underneath while typing

Tags: textbox, windows-phone-8, textchanged

So I am designing an app for Windows phone 8 and I was wondering if there is a way for me to have a text box where the user can search for some value in a data structure, and as the user is typing it will start giving them results, and as they are entering more text it will give less results as there will be less and less matches? I am thinking of using the textchanged event and search through the datas tructure constantly, but that seems like it will be very slow as it will be doing it after every new letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `AutoCompleteBox` from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/):

[image]